# How should I split joined lines for my paint app in java

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent, mousemotionlistener, mousemotionevent

I am new to using paint and lines in java, sorry if the answer is obvious. Never the less I would like to have my lines smooth and that is why I have the "Circles" join as to make a line with rounded corners, the problem is it doesn't recognize when the mouse is released so when I try to write another letter it connects the two points across the scree. What is the best way to program my application to have smooth lines with out being connected?

```
package pac;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Frame extends JPanel{

    private final ArrayList<Point> point = new ArrayList<>();

    public Frame() {
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                point.add(event.getPoint());
                repaint();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            point.add(event.getPoint());
            repaint();
        }
    });
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.setColor(new Color(0, 0, 128));
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(15f,
                                 BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,
                                 BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND));
 //   if(!mouserelased) {
        for (int i = 1; i < point.size(); i++)
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(point.get(i-1), point.get(i)));
 //   }
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.add(new Frame());
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(800, 600);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Have a `List` of a `List` of `Point`s; ie `List<List<Point>>`, so each "inner" list contain points which should be joined

Comment: @MadProgrammer The Java-2D based [`GeneralPath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) is good for situations like this. E.G. [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686753/418556), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7218309/418556), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20799711/418556) ..